# USB Remote Debugging on Windows 8 Phone

Tags: debugging, usb, windows-phone-8, remote-debugging

I want to test my Windows 8 phone app. I want to plug it into the desktop computer and view the JavaScript console output on the desktop. 
I can debug the app itself in Visual Studio but I want to see the JavaScript console output.
Is this possible? I know you can do it with Android phone

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#enable-usb-debugging

but what about the Windows 8 phone? What about previous versions of the windows phone? What about the different versions of the iOS?

Comment: Do you want to debug the javascript on a webpage on WP8? Or an actual app itself?

Comment: Both but I am more concerned about the JS since we can debug the app itself in Visual Studio right?

Comment: Correct. I think you might want to rephrase your question then. Make it more explicit that you are trying to debug the javascript in a webpage, as opposed to an app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do this on Windows Phone 8.

There is no information available about what may be possible in future versions.

Unfortunately, you'll have to show your output on the page to debug web pages on actual devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WEINRE](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) (WEb INspector REmote). It works with all platforms and it's free.

This is documented on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/Use-weinre-WP8-and-IE10-to-debug-your-mobile-HTML5-page-remotely)

Answer (score 1):

Launch Visual Studio and press Ctrl + Shift + P (or navigate to Debug > Other Debug Targets > Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer).